# Modernizr shows CSS-Columns support for browsers that don't support?

Tags: multiple-columns, modernizr, safari6

I'm working on a layout with CSS-Columns. To know about the browser's support, I'm loading modernizr.js. Now, I was opening my website in Safari 6.1, which does not support the CSS-Columns, but still, I get the following  element:

```
<html lang="en" class=" js csscolumns no-firefox">...</html>
```

Shouldn't modernizr be telling me a class like no-csscolumns?

Answer (score 0):

Safari has [supported css columns since Safari 3](http://caniuse.com/#search=columns) - you just need to use the `-webkit-` prefix